# Get all value from For loop in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Hi I am new in robot framework,
I need to click in some element with xpath.
I get the number of element and stored in a variable ${element}
when I run my code it found ${element}=4

Now I want to click on each element.
So i tried to get all index in a variable like ${i1} untill ${i4}
The result should give me this:

```
    ${i1} = 0
    ${i2} = 1
    ${i3} = 2
    ${i4} = 3
```

i tried this

```
:FOR  ${i}  IN  RANGE   0   ${element}
\   log ${i}
```

But it gives result like

```
    20181101 19:21:07.269 : INFO : ${i}: 0
    20181101 19:21:08.269 : INFO : ${i}: 1
    20181101 19:21:09.269 : INFO : ${i}: 2
    20181101 19:21:10.269 : INFO : ${i}: 3
```

Thank you

Comment: Can u share exact output you are getting?

Comment: result is: 20181101 19:21:07.269 : INFO : Item: 0
20181101 19:21:07.269 : INFO : Item: 4  but i would like ${i1} until ${i4}

Comment: you can update in question. it is not clear here and only partial log appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved by using the keyword `Set (Test/Suite/Global) Variable` keyword. This takes two parameters and allows you to use variables in variables for creating the name.

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${element}    Set Variable    ${4}
    :FOR     ${i}     IN RANGE     0     ${element}
    \    Set Test Variable    ${i${i}}    ${i}
```

This results in the following Message Log in RED.

```
Starting test: Folder.Forloop I.TC
20181102 07:41:39.010 : INFO : ${element} = 4
20181102 07:41:39.033 : INFO : ${i0} = 0
20181102 07:41:39.044 : INFO : ${i1} = 1
20181102 07:41:39.055 : INFO : ${i2} = 2
20181102 07:41:39.064 : INFO : ${i3} = 3
Ending test: Folder.Forloop I.TC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A. Kootstra and Sidara Keo.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should be use Nest Variable of robotframework . you can find my sample below and its should be solve your current problem.

```
test
     ${i}    Set Variable    i
    :FOR    ${n}    IN RANGE    4
    \   ${x}    Evaluate    ${n}+1
    \   Set Test Variable    ${${i}${x}}    ${n}
    log to console      ${i3}
```

and the result is same as you expetcation

> ${i1} = 0
>       ${i2} = 1
>       ${i3} = 2
>       ${i4} = 3